# how can i run my android app on a android tablet

Tags: android

I have developed an application for my android phone(Samsung GT-S5830) using SDK:2.3.3. I want to run my application on android tab(Samsung GT-N7000).

As I connect my android tablet with PC (using Windows-7), the PC automatically install its USB drivers BUT when i run my application "Device Chooser" window does not show my Tablet.

This is my first experience of working on tablet. As a beginner whats changes I have need to do in my application to run it on the android tablet.

Yours help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled developer and debug options on the tablet? I have not worked with Android Tablets but I will assume that they have the same settings as the phones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your windows PC does install USB Drivers for mounting the tablet as a massStorage device.
 What you need is the `ADB Driver` (Android Debug Bridge) for your tablet.

[Try this link at XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1571943)

Comment: http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/Samsung/Samsung-Galaxy-S-USB-Driver-for-Windows-x64.shtml <- maybe works for you ;)

Comment: Thank and I cordially appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the checkbox for Debug mode?
Have you updated ADT and sdk updates (they also includes new driver for your device under windows).